# Vuex TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getters')

Tags: vuex

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getters')

I got this error if I use mapGetter.

I will share my code

```html
<template>
    <div id="product-list">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <div class="toolbar-holder">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Analyze</button>
        </div>
        <p>Start enter the product name and then select from matches list</p>
    </div>
    <div id="products">
        <ConProduct :productList = "productState.productList"/>
    </div>
    <div id="product-rec">
        <ProductRec :productRecList="productState.productRecList"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ConProduct from './ConProduct.vue';
import ProductRec from './ProductRec.vue';
import { mapGetters,mapActions} from 'vuex';
import store from '../../../store';
export default {
    name: 'ProductList',
    components: {
        ConProduct,
        ProductRec
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        productState: 'products/getState'
      })
    },
    beforeCreate(to, from, next) {
      store.dispatch('products/search').then(() => {
        next()
      });
      store.dispatch('products/rec').then(() => {
        next()
      });
    },
    
}
</script>
```

This is my full source code and I checked the store. and everything is exist correctly

Comment: I'm using Vue 3 and Vuex 4